Convergence Analysis of an Integral Involving Logarithmic and Trigonometric Functions
I am trying to see for what values of the parameter $p>0$ the integral $$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\ln(1-x+\sqrt{1+x^2})}{(e^x-\cos x)^p}\arctan\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[4]{x}+\sqrt[6]{x}}\right)dx$$ converges.
Let $$f(x)=\dfrac{\ln(1-x+\sqrt{1+x^2})}{(e^x-\cos x)^p}\arctan\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[4]{x}+\sqrt[6]{x}}\right)$$
The authors solution goes like this:
We know that $\ln(1-x+\sqrt{1+x^2})=\ln(1+(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x))\le\sqrt{1+x^2}-x$.
When $p>0$ we could also write $$\dfrac{1}{(e^x-\cos(x))^p}\le\dfrac{1}{(e^x-1)^p}$$ and there exists some number $x_0$ such that for $x\ge x_0$ $$\dfrac{1}{(e^x-\cos(x))^p}\le\dfrac{1}{(e^x-1)^p}<\dfrac{1}{x}.$$
We also have $\arctan\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[4]{x}+\sqrt[6]{x}}\right)<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, so $f(x)\le\dfrac{\pi}{2x^2}$.
I am puzzled about why $\dfrac{1}{(e^x-1)^p}<\dfrac{1}{x}$ holds for $x\ge x_0.$  Could someone explain this deduction to me? Also, how did they conclude that $f(x)\le\dfrac{\pi}{2x^2}$? This is not immediately apparent based on the inequalities they arrived at.

Given that for $p>0$
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{x}{(e^x-1)^p} = 0
$$
then for each $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $M>0$ such that
$$
\left|\frac{x}{(e^x-1)^p} - 0\right| < \varepsilon, \quad\text{for} \quad x > M.
$$
You can remove the $0$ and the absolute value, choose $\varepsilon = 1$ and you have
$$
\frac{x}{(e^x-1)^p}<1 \implies \frac{1}{(e^x-1)^p}<\frac{1}{x} \quad\text{for} \quad x > M.
$$

Also
$$
\sqrt{1+x^2}-x=\frac{(1+x^2)-x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+x}<\frac{1}{2x}
$$

Thank you for the response! Why can we remove the absolute value, though?

Beacuse $x>M>0$ and $(e^x-1)^p>0$

thank you, i got it! And then how did they arrive at the final inequality for $f(x)$?

@MathStudent, see edit

thanks, but then shouldn't it be $f(x)\le\dfrac{\pi}{4x^2}$?

@MathStudent yes, but $1/4 < 1/2$ so it is less sharp but not wrong
